# In dropwizard(using jdbi with dao and resource objects), How can I elegantly save user id/session in database table for each update?

Tags: dao, dropwizard, jdbi

I need to save user id or session id in few tables after each update to know which user made the change. The straightforward/naive approach is to pass user id or session id in each dao call in all the resources, and change every dao to take it as a parameter and then save in db.
Is there a better/modular/efficient approach to do this?

Comment: You could have a filter in case you mean session info from a resource call, and update everything in there? If you use guice you could have interceptors doing that work for you and annotate the methods that need this behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Guice (and dropwizard-guice library) inside your project, one option would be to create request scoped bean and inject its provider inside your dao. So you could create inside your `guice module`:

```
@Provides
@RequestScoped
public SessionInfo domainContext(HttpHeaders headers) {
    return new SessionInfo(headers.getHeaderString("sessionId"));
}
```

}

and then, inject `Provider<SessionInfo>` to your dao.

Another option is to implement request filter and set your session id header using `ThreadLocal`. It could be like this:

```
public class SessionContext {

    private static final ThreadLocal<String> session = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static String getSession() {
        return session.get();
    }

    public static void setSession(String sessionValue) {
        session.set(sessionValue);
    }
}
```

and simple filter:

```
@Provider
public class SessionFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {
        SessionContext.setSession(requestContext.getHeaderString("test"));
    }
}
```

You could then utilize `SessionContext` object inside your dao.